# Entire functions bounded along $\vert z\vert = R$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function such that $\forall \vert z \vert =R$, $f(z)\leq M$, then for each coefficient $C_k$ in its power series expansion $f(z)=\sum C_kz^k$, $$|C_k|\leq \frac{M}{R^k}$$

My approach was plugging in $f(Re^{i\theta})$ which is $\sum C_kR^ke^{ik\theta}$. So $$\sum C_kR^ke^{ik\theta} \leq M$$

and then suppose that $C_l = 0$ for $l\neq k$. Which leads to $$C_kR^ke^{ik\theta} \leq M$$ $$C_k \leq \frac{M}{R^Ke^{ik\theta}}$$

I am not sure what to do at this point or if my steps leading up to this are correct. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why can you assume that $C_l=0$ for $l\neq k$?

Comment: I suggest using the Cauchy integral formula and then bounding the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the function $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n,$ we have$$c_n=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}.$$
 Now use Cauchy's integral formula $$f^{(n)}(0)=\dfrac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz.$$ Also keep in mind that $$\left|\int_{|z|=R}\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right|\le\int_{|z|=R}\left|\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\right||dz|.$$ A simple version of the last inequality is given by [the ML inequality.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxhc62zprQAhXpr1QKHXkjB_IQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEstimation_lemma&usg=AFQjCNFPuxyhr7nR5uBaymBziyQcSk3inQ)